# Rotativa.NetCore Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.CookieAuthenticationOptions'

Tags: .net-core, rotativa

I am using Rotativa.NetCore on a .Net CORE 2.0 (latest version and etc) and I am getting the following error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.CookieAuthenticationOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: do you have the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All metapackage (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/) listed in your csproj? And, if so, which version of it are you using?

Comment: 2.0.3 - it is listed as a NUGET DEPENDENCY
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's code to update Rotativa.NetCore from .Net Core 1 to .Net Core 2.0 here: https://github.com/aaxelm/Rotativa.NetCore/pull/1/files?diff=split

Comment: @David could you explain I little more the necessairy changes for .Net Core 2.0.

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis Rotativa.NetCore was written for .Net Core 1. It uses the CookieAuthenticationOptions class which no longer exists in .Net Core 2. Therefore, to get Rotativa.NetCore to work on .Net Core 2, don't use the NuGet package. Instead download the source code from: github.com/aaxelm/Rotativa.NetCore, make the changes to the code outlined here: github.com/aaxelm/Rotativa.NetCore/pull/1/files?diff=split and then in Visual Studio, right click on your solution and add this project as an Existing Project to whatever it is that your working on. Hope that helps!