# Rotativa.Netcore works locally but not after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rotativa

I am using the latest Rotativa.NetCore assembly in a ASP.NET Core 2.1.1 project. The NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa.AspNetCore v. 1.0.6) does not work on deployment (win2016) but works locally (win10).

IIS on deployment gives 404 and the error log (stdout) shows this:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Exception
   at Rotativa.AspNetCore.WkhtmlDriver.Convert(String wkhtmlPath, String switches, String html, String wkhtmlExe)
   at Rotativa.AspNetCore.WkhtmltopdfDriver.ConvertHtml(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String switches, String html)
   at Rotativa.AspNetCore.ViewAsPdf.CallTheDriver(ActionContext context)
   at Rotativa.AspNetCore.AsResultBase.BuildFile(ActionContext context)
   at Rotativa.AspNetCore.AsResultBase.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Here is 'myproject' source

```
public IActionResult DownloadCertificate(int id)
{
    var model = getData(id);
    return new ViewAsPdf("PdfCertificate", model)
    {
        WkhtmlPath = "", // set the path to the Rotativa .exe files. works locally but not on deployment. 
        FileName = "Cert.pdf"
    };
}
```

I have tried changing `WkhtmlPath` to `"..\\Rotativa\\"` but no luck.

Troubleshooting I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48166956/560784 - apparently Rotativa is compiled against .NET Core 1.0:

> There's code to update Rotativa.NetCore from .Net Core 1 to .Net Core 2.0 here: https://github.com/aaxelm/Rotativa.NetCore/pull/1/files?diff=split

So, I downloaded the Rotativa source and updated to .NET core 2.0 accordingly, referenced the new assembly. Problem persists.

I have checked permssions as well. Rotativa folder gives IIS_IUSRS execute permissions (running ApplicationPoolIdentity).

What am I missing?

My local folder structure:

> c:\inetpub\myproject\myproject.dll + web.config and what not.
>   c:\inetpub\myproject\Rotativa{wkhtmltoimage.exe, wkhtmltopdf.exe,
>   wkhtmltox.dll}

My deployed folder structure:

> c:\inetpub\sites\myproject\myproject.dll + web.config and what not.
>   c:\inetpub\sites\myproject\wwwroot\ (static files)
>   c:\inetpub\sites\myproject\Rotativa{wkhtmltoimage.exe, wkhtmltopdf.exe,
>   wkhtmltox.dll}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out I needed to install `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2017 (x86)` - download here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/ or https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

1. I reverted to the official nuget (for easier future maintenance) https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa.AspNetCore v. 1.0.6
2. I added `RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env, "..\\Rotativa\\");` to `Startup.cs`
3. My final code looks like this:

Code:

```
public IActionResult DownloadCertificate(int id)
{
    var model = getData(id);
    return new ViewAsPdf("PdfCertificate", model)
    {
         FileName = "Cert.pdf"
    };
}
```

Comment: Which can be downloaded from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem for my project developed with asp netcore3.1 and solved after installing "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2017 (x86)". Please make sure to install the (x86) whether your OS is x64 or x86!  Thanks Sha!!

Answer (score 0):

For me I just need to install **Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2017 (x86)** on THE SERVER. Previously I have tried other solutions including installing them in localhost, all didnt work, I almost give up!